# Need help applying timer in C in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I want to create a timer in our C program so that it can print the variable after every 1 second.

Can anybody help me in doing this?

Comment: I recommend you do some hard work first.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use busy waiting, because you've got 100% CPU utilization.
You must use system function which turns process into sleeping mode for example `select()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

void your_callback()
{
    printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
}

int main()
{
    struct timeval t;

    while (1) {
        t.tv_sec = 1;
        t.tv_usec = 0;

        select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &t);

        your_callback();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If ***all*** you are interested in doing is printing the value of a variable at a one second interval, using [`time(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time) or [`clock(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock) as suggested in the other answers might suffice.  In general, I would not recommend these [busy-waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) techniques.

---

If your program is more complex, I suggest you investigate using the **[`alarm(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm)** or [`settimer(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer) function to asynchronously deliver a signal to your application at a one second interval.

The following example uses [`select(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) to block indefinitely in order to minimize CPU usage associated with busy-waiting techniques.  The blocking `select()` call is interrupted and returns when a signal is caught.  In the case of the `SIGALRM` signal, the `print_variable` flag is set and the value of `variable` is printed.

**Example 1:** *using `alarm()`*

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile unsigned int variable = 0;
volatile unsigned int print_variable = 0;

void alarm_handler(int signum)
{
    variable++;
    print_variable = 1;
    alarm(1);
}

int main()
{        
    signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
    alarm(1);

    for (;;)
    {
        select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (print_variable)
        {
            printf("Variable = %u\n", variable);
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>Note: Error checking was omitted from the above code for simplicity.</sup>

<sup>**A `printf()` function could have been called inside the `SIGALRM` handler, but calling non-reentrant functions in a signal handler is generally discouraged.**</sup>

---

A timeout of one second can also be passed to `select()`, but if it were interrupted by any signal, additional logic is necessary to ensure that the remainder of the one second timeout is honored.  Fortunately on Linux, `select()` modifies the timeout value to reflect the amount of time not slept.  This allows interruption cases to be detected followed by subsequent call(s) `select()` to complete the timeout.

**Example 2:** *using `select()`*

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

volatile unsigned int variable = 0;

int main()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    int val;

    for (;;)
    {
        tv.tv_sec = 1;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;

        do
        {
            val = select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        } while (val != 0 && errno == EINTR);

        printf("Variable = %u\n", ++variable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only second precision. Use `time(0)` which returns current time if `time.h` is included.

**update:**
Adding simple example which prints `10` in every second during `20` seconds:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int num = 20;
    int c = time(0);
    while(n--)
    {
        printf("%d\n", a);
        while(!(time(0) - c));
        c = time(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No I want to print a variable after every 1 second. So how our programme knows that 1 second passed so that it can print the variable.

Comment: Here `time(0) - c` will be 0(false) while current second is going.
Also you can use `Sleep()` in windows and `sleep()` in unix to sleep your program in specified time.

Answer (score 0):

use `time(0)` see this example

```
/* timer.c */ 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <time.h> 

void delay_sec( int seconds ){ 
    clock_t endwait; 
    endwait = clock () + seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
    while (clock() < endwait) {} 
} 

int main (void){ 
    time_t rawtime, ini_time, now; 
    struct tm *ptm; 

    time ( &ini_time ); 
    for(;;){ 
        time ( &rawtime ); 
        //ptm = gmtime ( &rawtime ); 
        //printf ("%2d:%02d:%02d\n", ptm_2->tm_hour, ptm_2->tm_min, ptm_2->tm_sec); 
        now = rawtime - ini_time; 
        ptm = gmtime ( &now ); 
        printf ("%2d:%02d:%02d\n", ptm->tm_hour, ptm->tm_min, ptm->tm_sec); 
        delay_sec(1); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you know `1000 Milliseconds` equals to `1 Second`.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <time.h>
#define mydelay 1000

void delay(int mseconds)
{
    clock_t wait = mseconds + clock();
    while (wait > clock());
}

int main()  
{  
   int i=100;
   while(1)
   {
           printf("%d\n",i);
           delay(mydelay);
   }              
   return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Actually in our programme I am creating 100 thread so it is taking time so i want to print the variable after every second without applying the wait our sleep.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example which prints the value of the variable `a` for every 1 sec:

```C
#include<stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
  int a = 10;
  while(a--)
  {
    printf("Value of a = %d\n", a);
    sleep(1);  
  }

}
```

Output:

> Value of a = 9
>   ...
>   value of a = 0